# Echo page description from Yoast on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, seo

I have installed Wordpress SEO by Yoast onto a site Im building. They have an area when you can add the description for the meta information.

However I want to add this to a twitter meta tag:

```
<meta name="twitter:description" content="">
```

Does anyone know how to grab the description and output it for a single page?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<?php echo wpseo_get_value('metadesc'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`wpseo_get_value('metadesc');` has been **deprecated**

Please use `WPSEO_Meta::get_value("metadesc");`

```
<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("metadesc"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add `twitter:description` meta data. Please follow below steps.

```
 - Login to admin panel
 - Go to menu item SEO->Social
 - Uncheck the checkbox Add Open Graph meta data
 - Go to tab Twitter
 - Check the checkbox Add Twitter card meta data
 - Click on save changes
```

Now if you visit the post page or any single page, you can see a meta tag with name twitter:description added to the head.

Hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks for this. However it only adds a select few tags and description was not one of them unfortunately.

Comment: @TonyHeyden It does add but you have to uncheck the open graph meta in the facebook tag. Then only you can add description tag.